# Full Of Abbreviations! (Part 2)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This is gonna be the second part of "Full Of Abbreviations", though not all will be about abbreviations

> In the beginning, I am an abbreviation of the whole word (Also found in games)
>
> With the middle, I am also an abbreviation you can find in games (Only 2 letters)
>
> While with the ending, you can use me to move something
>
> My Whole consists of just 8 letters

Huge Extra hint :

> I can be found in almost every home

Comment: This riddle still hasn't been answered yet? Must be pretty tough. $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: I'm considering putting a bounty on this? What do u think? I'm just afraid that this will be too easy. :) @user477343

Comment: Well, I have more reputation, and I like this puzzle. I am not sure but I think I might be able to put a bounty on this by the end of tomorrow? If you would like to have a bounty on this, I am more than happy to use my own rep. I suggest maybe providing a hint, instead, but it's up to you :D

Comment: Yeah, I'll add a hint first I guess and see how it goes until tomorrow :) @user477343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright this might be another stretch but...
Is it a

> Computer?

Abbreviation of the whole word

> Comp which is short for computer

Can be found in games

> MP or magic power found in rpg games. Also 2 letters

The ending is where I may be wrong

> Put. To move anything you take it from one place and "put" it at another place. Also almost everyone has a computer

Comment: Answer is correct but what I meant by ending was just the "put" part :) Will give checkmark once u correct that :D

Comment: Ah I see. I edited it :) @KevinL

Comment: Yep. All correct, nicely done :)

Comment: I just realized this but the first part is almost correct. What I meant was Rot13 (pbz) which is commonly found in games where you can vs bots :)

Comment: Yea I saw. But in some games it had that extra letter so that was what struck me first

Comment: Oh okay, nvm then :)